# May I have a res.json and res.sendFile together in the same api endpoint in express?

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, express

I want upload the content of an excel file into the server in order to get its data and do some stuff...
I came up with the following code, however it seems like it is not working properly as the following error displays in the console `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

The file is getting uploaded into the folder and the json message is being displayed... However I do not know if I am going to face any issue in the future...

Actually I just need the excel data no need for the excel being uploaded... Maybe you could give me a workaround, guys...

```
const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path
        .extname(file.originalname)
        .toLowerCase()}`
    );
  },
});

const excelFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype.includes('excel') ||
    file.mimetype.includes('spreadsheetml')
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb('Please upload only excel file.', false);
  }
};
const upload = multer({
  storage,
  fileFilter: excelFilter,
});

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  var workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.file.path);
  var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
  var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
  res.json(xlData).sendFile(`/${req.file.path}`, { root: path.resolve() });
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just send it as a single ```Object```? res.send({json:JSON.stringify(xlData), filePath:`/${req.file.path}`, ... others})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May I have a res.json and res.sendFile together in the same api endpoint in express?

No, you cannot.  Each of those methods, sends a complete http response (including calling `res.end()` which terminates the http request) and you can only send one http response to each incoming request.  The particular error you're getting has to do with the `res.sendFile()` trying to configure the response that it's getting ready to send and finding that the http response object has already been used for sending a response and can't be used again.

Ordinarily, if you wanted to sent two different pieces of data, you would just combine them into a single Javascript object and just call `res.json()` on the object that contains both pieces of data.

But, sending a binary file is not something you can easily put in a JSON package.  You could construct a multipart response where one part was the JSON and one part was the file.  You could JSON encode binary data (though that's inefficient).  I presume there are probably some modules that would help you do that, but for most clients, that isn't what they are really expecting or equipped to handle.

The only way to a proper solution is for us to understand what client/server workflow you're trying to implement here and why you're trying to send back the same file that was just uploaded.  There would normally not be a reason to do that since the client already has that data (they just uploaded it).